# String set difference

Tags: python, string, set, difference

I have two sets of strings: `a` and `b`

```
type(a)
set

type(b)
set

a
{'South 2nd Street'}

b
{'8921 South 2nd Street'}
```

In order to find the difference between these two sets, I apply the `difference()` function, which I would like to return `8921`  but instead returns the entire string

```
b.difference(a)
{'8921 South 2nd Street'}
```

I'm guessing this happens because those sets are being compared by what character is at index 0, 1, 2, 3 and so on (in which case `a` is completely different from `b`)

What is the correct way, then, to get the combined difference(s) between two strings in Python without using set difference?  In this case, the output should be `8921`

Comment: "which should return 8921  but instead returns the entire string" no, it shouldn't. Why do you *believe* it should? Those two set objects contain two different objects, so obviously, the difference will be that object. "I'm guessing this happens because those sets are being compared by what character is at index 0, 1, 2, 3 and so on (in which case a is completely different from b)" No, *it's comparing the two different objects in the set*.

Comment: No, that is not known in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sets contain the entire address as a single element, not separate elements for each word.

You need to split the string into words, and make a set of that.

```
a = set('South 2nd Street'.split())
b = set('8921 South 2nd Street'.split())
print(b.difference(a))
{'8921'}
```